# Problem in inserting more number of records if it is transaction based

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

In our application we allow user to enter email ids comma separated.
We take the email ids separate it and insert as records in a table.

When they enter email ids less than 10000, everything goes fine.
If it goes beyond 10000 the whole application hangs, we are not able to login the application.

Technical Details

1. Java Servlet and JSP running in Tomcat server.
2. Database - Postgres

Note: The whole insert process is transaction based, that is if we face any problem in 
inserting a single email id and the insert fails the whole inserts roles back.

Comment: Can you clarify if "When they enter email ids less than 10000" means that if you try to process > 10000 records, it hangs, or that the application hangs if one of the IDs entered has a value > 10000 ?

Comment: It is 10000 records not email id length > 10000

Comment: Frank has nailed it down. This is not per se a JSP/Servlet/PostgreSQL problem, but more a JDBC (or JDBC driver) problem. How are you doing it? Plain JDBC? Hibernate? JPA? Batches?

Comment: It is plain JDBC type IV driver "postgresql-8.2-508.jdbc4.jar", with PGPOOL for connection management.

Comment: Are you sending the data using a `POST` request?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an applicationproblem, PostgreSQL has no problem with 10k new records within a single transaction. We load GBs of data within a single transaction, works great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with transaction block. When we removed the transaction block,
the inserts were also fast. As well as application was also working fine.

Thanks for answering.